# Adding bold tag to a string in pdf

Tags: python, machine-learning

How can I able add bold font style to a specific string in a PDF. I tried to read the PDF using TIKA. Now I have to search for a specific string and display it as bold string. How it can be done in python?

```
ot = welcome to python programming
regex=r"python"
print(ot.replace(regex,"<b>"+regex+"</b>"))
```

Since I read the pdf using TIKA, the matched word is printed along bold tags.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Why do you use regex=r"python" when all you are doing at the end is a simple string replacing. Did you try to do it by removing the `r` from the start of the `r"python"`?

Comment: Thanks for the idea@SRC still i am getting the output  
 welcome to <b> python</b> programming

Comment: @SRC and this is just an example. In real i need to search a specific word so i am using regex

Comment: I am not sure what you want actually, it seems that you are successfully adding the <b> and </b> on both sides of `python` is not what you wanted in the first place?

Comment: @SRC actually I am having resumes in a pdf format. From that I have to highlight the technologies they have studied and used,the previous company's name etc. So I am trying to extract those string using regex and and trying to give external link to that matched strings. So finally my output will be like, if I opened a resume I should be able to view the resume and also able to open the company's profile and technologies details if I click that string.